# MongoDB mongorestore and existing collection with records

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I need to import (restore) a collection generated with `mongodump` into an existing database and I'd like the records to be merged into the existing collection.

Does `mongorestore` merge the records in the same collection or it will drop the existing collection before restoring the records?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

`mongorestore` will only drop the existing collection if you use the `--drop` argument.

If you don't use `--drop`, all documents will be inserted into the existing collection, unless a document with the same `_id` already exists. Documents with the same `_id` will be skipped, they are not merged. So `mongorestore` will never delete or modify any of the existing data by default.

Comment: is the mongodb actually being dropped with using option --drop? In mine case, on restore, i can see the previous records that was added after taking the dump. can you solve my issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424347/drop-whole-database-within-a-single-command-of-restoring-the-dump-of-mongodb

Comment: Mongorestore ref for the answer above: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#behavior

Comment: @codeofnode from the documentation: `--drop does not drop collections that are not in the backup.`. You should verify that the collection you expect to be dropped is indeed present in the backup.