# drop whole database within a single command of restoring the dump of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database-restore, mongorestore

I am trying to restore the directory dump of mongodb.

i am doing

```
mongorestore --db mydb --drop path/to/mydb/dump
```

But both does not able to restore the state of my dump.
Any new records are visible even after restoring the db.

But no error is shown on console.

Comment: drop the tables first if you don't want old data there.

Comment: thats why i am using --drop in command, but still new records are visible

Comment: how should i drop all the collections (or drop whole database) within the above command then restore the dump

Comment: Please direct your administration questions to [dba.stack.exchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/?newreg=3ed9e0f1c2454bf2bb8b61d7451f541d). Stack Overflow is for programming topics.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see an answer and I had the same question today.

You can drop the database before with:

```
use <db>
db.dropDatabase()
```

Or you can only drop the collection with:

```
db.<collection>.drop()
```

The problem with your command could be that something misses, like the database which you authenticate against or the user or maybe another thing.

In my setup this works

```
mongorestore --username=<user> --db=<database> --authenticationDatabase=<database> --dir=<dumpdir> --drop
```

If your dump was zipped beforehand, you can add the --gzip flag in the end.

You can find all that in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.dropDatabase/index.html) for dropping a database or in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/index.html) of dropping a whole database. But please be cautious with it.